# Trigger browser back when cursor is not on a text input or area

Tags: java, gwt

How do make the browser back trigger with GWT, when the mouse cursor is not on a text input or text area?

However when its on a text input or text area, pressing back should function as a text backspace and not trigger browser back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. Just call the register method in order to set a the listener.

```
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.KeyCodes;
import com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerRegistration;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewEvent;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.Event.NativePreviewHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.History;

public class BackPreviewHandler implements NativePreviewHandler {

    private HandlerRegistration handlerRegistration;

    @Override
    public void onPreviewNativeEvent(final NativePreviewEvent event) {
        if (event.getTypeInt() == Event.ONKEYDOWN) {
            if (event.getNativeEvent().getKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_BACKSPACE) {
                Element elemPointedByMouse = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
                String tagName = elemPointedByMouse.getTagName();
                System.out.println(tagName);

                if (!tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("INPUT") 
                        && !tagName.equalsIgnoreCase("TEXTAREA")) {

                    History.back();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void register() {
        handlerRegistration = Event.addNativePreviewHandler(this);
    }

    public void deregister() {
        handlerRegistration.removeHandler();
    }
}
```